# What really is partial_fit() in SKLearn's Birch Clustering, and can it be used in very large datasets?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

My data is light tailed, with several outliers in both extreme ends. I am doing a clustering of the data using Birch, prior to that I used RobustScaler to transform the data, then used PCA to reduce the dimension. However I am receiving a MemoryError:
[image]

This is somewhat unusual for me because when I try a different transformation method that only maps the raw data from [0,1], Birch algorithm works.

I read SKLearn's Birch documentation and came around the partial_fit() function but there is not enough detail there for me to understand its purpose and how to use it.The documentation simply says: 'Online learning. Prevents rebuilding of CFTree from scratch.'

Answer (score 0):

**Look at the source code.**

Don't rely on people on web forums to guess what the function does when you have access to the source. The reason is simple: **it can vary across versions**. So I could be giving you a right answer, for a different version...

Did you call `partial_fit` on the entire data at once? That is not what you are supposed to do. Process one batch at a time only.

Memory problems can arise from old data still being reachable and not garbage collected (such as the non-transformed data), but also due to different parameters. If you study the Birch paper carefully, you'll see that it expects *much* closer control over memory than we have in today's languages like Python, and at this detailed level is unreproducible on modern operating systems.

But the main questions you should be considering are the following two:

1. Is the quality of Birch clustering on this data actually good enough? Or are you trying hard to solve the wrong problem?
2. How much does the quality degrade if you'd only use 50% of your "big" data? Statistically it shouldn't matter... The method is based on aggregates, and the precision of such aggregates grows with sqrt(n)... I.e., adding more and more data doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi Thanks of the comment, I did not use partial_fit() yet, that result showed on the image is based on Birch [without the partial_fit()]. I was wondering if partial_fit() can be used to scale birch clustering, even with the source code at hand, it seems like it runs an iteration of batches, but again it is still good to hear advice from people who have used this function first hand.